# Typescript definition file not being recognized?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, typescript, bower

I'm trying to use the angular-spinner directive in my app. Since I'm using typescript, I wanted to create a definition file for it. (I know there's one from definitelyTyped, however it's not available using bower anymore and I don't want to use another package manager)

#### Client/support/angular-spinner.d.ts

```
interface ISpinnerService {

    spin(key: string): void;
    stop(key: string): void;
}
```

#### Client/_references.ts

```
/// <reference path="../bower_components/dt-angular/angular.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../bower_components/dt-angular/angular-route.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../bower_components/dt-jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../bower_components/dt-angular-ui-bootstrap/angular-ui-bootstrap.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="support/angular-spinner.d.ts" />
```

#### Client/app/app.ts

```
/// <reference path="../_references.ts" />

module App {

    var dependencies = [
        "ngRoute",
        "ui.bootstrap",
        "angularSpinner",
    ];
...
```

#### Controller

```
/// <reference path="../../_references.ts" />
...
constructor(spinnerService: ISpinnerService) { ... }
```

When I run grunt-tsng, the following error occurs:

```
Warning: Error: Can't resolve dependency for controller XXX 
with name ISpinnerService Use --force to continue.
```

Did I missed something?

Comment: It is always worth starting the path in the current folder in circumstances such as this: `/// <reference path="./support/angular-spinner.d.ts" />`

Comment: Just a suggestion `however it's not available using bower anymore and I don't want to use another package manager` TypeScript has its own requirements. TSD is *designed* to support them. Work with the tools of the language you are working with.

Comment: @basarat: Now I fetch application dependencies with .nuget, node modules with npm, javascript client side code with bower and typedefs with tsd. I see your point, but this is getting ridiculous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Warning: Error: Can't resolve dependency for controller XXX

You need to have `spinnerService` as a `Service` implemented as a `class` and not just an `interface`

Comment: This is my understanding of the error aswell, however if I'd use the type definition for angular-spinner directly insteat of copied code, I wouldn't get more than an interface too: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angular-spinner/angular-spinner.d.ts